# Chrome Dev Tools network panel behaving strangely

Tags: google-chrome

I've been having some strange behavior when using Chrome Dev Tools:

(1) In the Network Tab.  When I rollover a bar in the Waterfall section, I only numbers, now. The bars that visualize the numbers are gone!

[image]

I've checked the settings with my Chrome Canary (which does display the bars)...and they are exactly the same.

This is what it should look like (from Chrome Canary) ... notice the bars in the rollover timing panel.
[image]

I also tried to "Restore defaults and reload" from the Settings/Preferences.

Also, tried to open up an Incognito window so that Extensions are disabled.

None of this worked.

Anybody else experience this? If so, how did you fix it?

** Update **
A co-worker is also experiencing this too.  None of us changed any settings in our browsers.  I'm suspecting that somehow our IT department is controlling our Chrome browser settings.

Comment: How did you verify that the settings are exactly the same?

Comment: Went into the Dev Tools Settings Preferences.... I also clicked on "Restore defaults and reload".